# How to use or enable openssl in xampp

Tags: php, openssl, xampp

I'm configuring my xampp, and having issues with xampp enabling openssl with php, how do I do it?

Comment: usually it just works. Please tell us what error you encounter

Comment: so how exactly does openssl work?  Isn't for encrypting the html form information?

Comment: No, that's mod_ssl in the Apache server. The PHP openssl functions are mostly needed for in-application data encryption purposes. It also provides the file API with https:// request support. From the phrasing of your question I would proclaim that you don't need it.

Comment: So how do I make sure my html form is HTTPS and the messages from the form are sent encrypted?  How do I go about doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Design your forms to use `action="https://...."` to encrypt the transmission. Setup a server certificate and enable mod_ssl in the Apache config.

The PHP openssl functions do not enter the picture for that. You will only need the openssl commandline tool once for generating a self signed certificate, if you didn't aquire a commercial one.